# apache, php - request timeout

Tags: php, apache, symfony1

Good day to all.

I have a little funny trouble that I don't really know how to... begin debugging.

I have a site with some articles and other stuff, based on symfony (http://www.magazinulprogresiv.ro/). Nothing unusual till now.

The funny part is that sometimes it works ok, sometimes it gives timout (for the same page).

The thing is that I received it for debugging, I didn't make it so I can't provide 2 many details. All I'm asking is: do you think is an apache problem (that's my personal opinion till now, I started some logging but I'll get the data later)? Or you think is code related (I would have excluded this but it seems that there have been some code changing recently and no server changes and before this it was working ok)?

The problem was first spotted on: http://www.magazinulprogresiv.ro/articol/118/Magazinul_tip_convenience.html, but I managed 2 reproduce it on homepage, and other pages.

Edited: added screen shot. Also I managed to reproduce with an image so is almost definitely apache problem (although it reproduced much more harder).

[image]

Comment: You start debugging webserver problems by looking at the server's logs. What's in the error log? Anything relevant around the times these timeouts occur?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could provide more details about your specific problem, you haven't given us much to work with at all.

Comment: That's all I have also... that's why I asked only for an opinion... I doubt that with that information any1 could provide a clear answer... all I ask are suggestions. Also: If I try to access a specific file (an image for example) all is fine... this is also pointing to some coding problem. P.S. I'm also waiting for the logs but I doubt I will have them today (I have no ssh access yet is scheduled for tommorow).

Comment: Please add some more information, as in, where you get the error? the EXACT WORDING of the error you're getting? maybe a screenshot or a live demo?

Comment: A potential issue, that page is loading a MASSIVE amount of content as separate files; tons of images (and I don't see where they;re being used) and download times for all of them adds up greatly. Since the site is inefficient like that, the server may simply be overloaded with requests and time out on some of them.

Comment: @SirTapTap: I tested you theory... looks believable (got some timeouts for some elements). Could this end in a general timeout?

Comment: It should only occur if one request gets a full timeout (usually 5 seconds or so) with no data returned from the server. However since you have a great deal of slow elements, I would try and fix as much of that as you can to improve load times regardless of the timeout issue, and it should make the timeouts less likely if the page is loaded more efficiently. Sorry I can't diagnose exactly where the page is timing out. Also make sure your PHP script isn't taking more than several seconds; As Alex Angelico stated that may aslo result in a timeout. However it wasn't THAT slow when I visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Well not exactly but is not my problem any more. I was looking for  the logs when suddenly the server stop working. So I pinged it and ping failed. So the problem is kind of clear and is the hosting. (server not responding to ping kind of eliminates any programming issues.)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if the scripts takes too long, the server respond with a timeout. 
If you are debugging and stop the execution for too long (not sure how much, a minute or so) the server shows a timeout. 
I think your script is in a loop or something like that.